# C++11 Given input, initialize template to be used outside if statement

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm doing a C++ assignment where we have to use C++11. The first line of input is either "**numbers**" or "**strings**" which should be used to initialize a template that I wrote. I can use an if statement to check which word is used, and right now this is what I have:

```
if (next.compare("NUMBERS")) {
   LinkedList<int>* list = new LinkedList();
} else if (next.compare("STRINGS")) {
   LinkedList<string>* list = new LinkedList();
}
```

The problem with doing this of course is that I can't use the list outside of the if statement. I need to use the list outside of the if statement but I don't know how to declare it outside of the if statement without filling in a template value.  I tried looking up if it was possible to just create a template and cast it later but I was wondering if there is a better solution before I continue to pursue that.

The assignment requires that I write the `LinkedList` class myself so I don't need a solution that uses a `LinkedList` created already for me or a solution with vectors since that would defeat the purpose of the assignment. I have to use my own template.

Comment: `LinkedList<std::variant<int, string>>` ? Or `boost::variant` if you have to use C++11 but you can use third party libraries.

Comment: Without knowing more about your assignment, perhaps an abstract base-list class which defined the interface, and then use pointers to that base-list class? There are other possible ways to solve it too, including deeper and more usage of templates.

Comment: Or you could just use `std::string` always and convert them into int's if it's `NUMBERS`.

Answer (score -1):

You code structure will change based on what you want to do with the list after creation, you may want to create a pointer to two lists outside of your if statements, and then choose which one to use based on which was instantiated.

```
LinkedList<int>*    intList     = new LinkedList<int>();
LinkedList<string>* stringList  = new LinkedList<string>();

if(next.compare("NUMBERS)){
    LinkedList<int>*    intList     = new LinkedList<int>();
} else if (next.compare("STRINGS")){
    LinkedList<string>* stringList  = new LinkedList<string>();
}

//do something with either list
```

Comment: That's no different from what's already is being done. And using pointers which makes it worse.